# Angular run single test (not fdescribe or fit)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a project with tons of tests which are not maintained and therefore if I run `ng test` the build fails due to some import problems in `.spec.ts` etc.

Is there a way to **run a single file test** of a service? Maybe with help of PhpStorm. I have no time to cleanup all the tests to run a single file.

I tried to run `karma start path-to-config --spec path-to-test-file` but it ended up with error that Angular's tests are supposed to be run using `ng test`.
Also I've tried to use `--main` flag with `ng test` but this also build the whole application.

I want to run only one UNIT test which doesn't require any application part to exist, so I don't understand why it tries to compile whole application.

`fdescribe` and `fit` also result in build fail.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the following line in test.ts file to run a single test

`let context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts/);`

to

`let context = require.context('./', true, /XYZ\.spec\.ts/);`

here, XYZ.spec.ts is a test file you want to run.